# Input in python on more than one line

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, input, user-input

This is my code

```
fw = open('input.txt', 'w')
fw.write(input())
fw.close()
fr = open('input.txt', 'r')
for y in fr:
    print(y)
fr.close()
```

When the user writes into the file. How can he go to the next line?

Whenever I hit enter it accepts only one line and does not go to the next line.

example:
When I run this code, I input

```
1 2 3 4
```

The output is same as input.
But I want it to be written as

```
1
2
3
4
```

in the input.txt file.

I tried the following and did not work.

1. `fw.write(input() + "\n")`
2. `fw.write(input("\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever i hit enter it accepts only one line and does not go to the next line.

Yes, `input` take only 1 line as input.

You can either, use a [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response?rq=1) until a certain response is given, or use `split` to split your input and then write each item on the list on a new line:

```
fw.write('\n'.join(input().split(' ')))
```

or

```
userInput = input()
for line in userInput.split(' '):
    fw.write(line)
```

Comment: you could use `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')` to allow arbitrary whitespace such as tabs (`'\t'`). You should append `'\n'` in the second code example or use `print(line, file=fw)`

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop. Try this:

```
fw = open('input.txt', 'w')
while 1:
    info = input('enter stop to stop:')
    if info == 'stop':
        break
    fw.write(info)

fw.close()
fr = open('input.txt', 'r')

for y in fr:
    print(y, end='')
fr.close()
```

Comment: You could also use `for y in fr`

Answer (score 1):

To print each whitespace-separated item in the input string on its own line:

```
print(*input().split(), sep='\n', file=fw)
```